# Как получать данные от websocket в разных методах класса, если приём возможен только в одном месте?

Tags: python, websocket, asyncio

Если лень разбираться что я сделал, напишите пожалуйста свой вариант

Действия происходят в классе. Используется asycncio библиотека websockets

- Я реализовал получение данных в одном методе, который запущен в
  цикле.
- Есть метод для обработки полученных данных. В этом методе я
  заполняю поле класса, которое является буфером приёма последнего
  сообщения.
- Есть метод, который отправляет запрос на новые подписки. Этот    метод
  должен получить сообщение об успешной подписке.

  Есть метод получения данных. В нём зависает всё и новые данные не поступают.
  Пример кода.

```
class WS(object):
    def __init__(self, loop):        
        self._received_buf = list()
        loop.create_task(self.start())    
    
    async def start(self):
        while True:     # Outer loop restarted every time the connection fails
            try:
                url = "xxxxxxxxxx"
                async with websockets.connect(url, loop=self._loop) as self._websocket:
                    await self._subscribe_instruments()
   
                    while True:     # listener loop
                        try:
                            ws_reply = json.loads(await asyncio.wait_for(self._websocket.recv(), timeout=5))
                            await self._reply_process(ws_reply)
    
                        except(asyncio.TimeoutError, websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed):
                            try:
                                await self._check_connection()
                                continue
    
                            except Exception as exp:                                
                                break  # inner loop
            except socket.gaierror:                
                continue
            except ConnectionRefusedError:                
                continue
    
    async def _reply_process(self, response):
        self._received_buf = response
    
        smth important...
        
    async def _get_response(self, response_type: int, data_request):
        if response_type == ResposeType.NEW_STREAM:
            while True:
                do important code...
                await asyncio.sleep(0.001) 
    
    async def create_stream(self, stream_id, stream_topic):
        data = [PacketType.SUBSCRIBE, stream_id, stream_topic]
        await self._websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
        result = await self._get_response_unsafe(ResposeType.NEW_STREAM, data)
        # print(f'create stream {result}')
        # return result
```

Comment: Чем не устраивают готовые библиотеки работы с websocker'ами?

Comment: Я как раз использовал такую. Вопрос решил при помощи Asyncio Futures